# Tutorials for 'mastering' Google search?

Tags: google-search

**Background**

It is a simple question but I have realized that maybe my usage of search engines (mainly Google) is rather naive.

I am aware of using quotes ("") to search for exact occurrence of multiple words, and the asterix (*) as a placeholder for any word. I am also aware of "filetype:" and "Define:"

**Question**

Could somebody here please recommend any nice online tutorials/books/videos (preferably videos) for **mastering Google search?** Or perhaps if you could list some nice tips & tricks you've learnt along the way - even if it just involves suggestions for best practice.

Comment: Google isn't computer software, which makes this question off topic. Asking for learning material is also not encouraged on any Stack Exchange site, sorry.

Comment: Google search is computer software isn't it...?

Comment: No – we define computer software as something running locally on your machine. Google Search is a web app. Questions about web app are better suited for [webapps.SE], however your question is not on topic for Web Apps either, as it's opinion-based and only asking for learning material.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

My top two `Google` searches for this topic resulted in:

1. [Google Guide](http://www.googleguide.com/)
2. [Google Search Education](http://www.google.ca/insidesearch/searcheducation/)